# Java3D and HexGrid Coordinates

Tags: java, positioning, java-3d, coordinate

I'm trying to figure out a way to find if a Point3f is inside or on the edge of grid made of Hexagons (which are each one a specific Shape3D Object).

The idea would be to change the color of the Hexagon cointaing the Point3f or both Heaxgons if the point is on an edge.

To make the grid i used this logic http://playtechs.blogspot.com/2007/04/hex-grids.html
So it should be fairly easy to know how Hexagon are located from each others.

My problem is related to coordinates, there is the structure i use in SceneGraph :

BranchGroup > TransformGroup > Hexagrid (TransformGroup) > HexaRow (TranformGroup) > Hexagon (Shape3D)

Each TransfromGroup is created with a Transform3D(Vector3F) to position it in 3D space

I would like to recover the coordinates of each Hexagon from BranchGroup because my Point3f will be generate on the root of the SceneGraph.

I tried to put Vertex coordinates in a HashMap  where Point is the coordinate in the grid of the Hexagon, and Point3f[] is the coordinates in 3d space of each vertex of the Hexagon.
I did that while adding the Hexagon on the row, but since the is 3 Vectors to place the structure until that step with each one a Local coordinate system I coulnd't have it to work properly.

Is there an easier way to find the coordinates of a Shape3d Object without having to add all the Vectors used to get to it ?

Is it even a proper way to archieve my goal ? (from what I undersood collision detection works only with 2 Object and I really need to know if my Point is on an edge , makes 3 Object)

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Well, finaly i found a better approach, using Transform3D mul method

```
    translateRootTG.addChild(hexaGrid);

    Polygon myPolygon = hexaGrid.getPolygon(19,1);
    // Get the First TransformGroup that containt the first Translation
    TransformGroup firstTransform= (TransformGroup)myPolygon.getParent();
    // the the Second TransfromGroup that containt the secondary Translation
    TransformGroup secondTransform = (TransformGroup)myPolygon.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();
    // Get the Transform3D from the first TransformGroup
    Transform3D firstTranslation = new Transform3D(); 
    firstTransform.getTransform(firstTranslation); // put the Transform in T3D var
    // Get the Transform3D from the second TransformGroup
    Transform3D secondTranslation = new Transform3D(); 
    secondTransform.getTransform(secondTranslation); // put the Transform in T3D var

    // Mul Transform3D to have complete translation
    Transform3D t3DTotalPolygon = new Transform3D();
    t3DTotalPolygon.mul(firstTranslation, secondTranslation);

    TransformGroup tgTest = new TransformGroup(t3DTotalPolygon);
    tgTest.addChild(new ColorCube(0.03f));
    translateRootTG.addChild(tgTest);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
javax.media.j3d.Node/Shape3D.getLocalToVworld(Transform3D t)
```